# Python list intersection with non unique items

Tags: python, intersection, multiset

I have two strings and I would like to have the intersection on them *including* duplicate items:

```
str_a = "aabbcc"
str_b = "aabd"

list(set(str_a) & set(str_b))
>> "ab"
```

I would like to have it return:

```
>> "aab"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `"aab"` rather than `"aaaabbb"` or `"aabb"`?

Comment: Because thats what I want. The functional question is: give me all words (str_a) that can be constructed from a given input of letters (str_b).

Comment: Right, but what rule are you applying such that that is the right answer? If you just want to operate on those two specific strings, you can just hard code that into an if statement.

Comment: Yeah, but obviously this is the stripped down version of what I really want to do. No sense in letting people read tons of lines if my problem can be shown in a couple of lines...

Comment: That still does not tell us what the rule here is supposed to be. Until you tell us that, this question is under specified. It happens that there is a python library that performs this one operation correctly, which is great, but this question remains under-specified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Multisets are implemented in python 2.7 or later as (mutable) `Counter` objects. You can perform many of the same operations as you can for sets, such as union, intersection, difference (though counts can become negative), etc.:

```
from collections import Counter as mset
```

Solution:

```
(mset("aabbcc") & mset("aabd")).elements()
```

More details:

```
>>> intersection = mset("aabbcc") & mset("aabd")
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})

>>> list(intersection.elements())
['a', 'a', 'b']

>>> ''.join(intersection.elements())
'aab'
```

You can use `''.join` if you want a string, or `list()` if you want a list, though I would just keep it in iterable format as `intersection.elements()`.

Comment: This isn't at all what he's asking for.  He wants the *intersection* of the strings.

Comment: This is the union of the elements, rather than the intersection.

Comment: @Blckknght: oops sorry, fixing

Comment: It's not even the union, it's the multiset sum (the union for instance would contain only two "a"s).

Comment: @ninjagecko: not quite, your `intersection` output is incorrect, and confusing as well.

Comment: Thanks. Not as fast as the sets, but that is to be expected.

Comment: @Jon: you can do `help(Counter)` or see http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I do not find this confusing at all. I'm confounded how you can accuse this answer of being confusing, when you later posted the exact same answer, almost line-for-line.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Your code line `>>> intersection = ...` would not echo the output on the terminal. You are missing an explicit `>>> intersection`. Moreover, until you edited the `Counter([{..}])` output, your example was incorrect. Last but not least, while I was entering my answer and testing it on the prompt, your answer was still quite incorrect. I can assure you that if our answers appeared similar, that was entirely a coincidence.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for each word and use these as sets:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> str_a, str_b = 'aabbcc', 'aabd'
>>> Counter(str_a) & Counter(str_b)
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
>>> ''.join((Counter(str_a) & Counter(str_b)).elements())
'aab'
```

The `Counter` is a `dict` subclass, but one that counts all the elements of a sequence you initialize it with. Thus, `"aabbcc"` becomes `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2})`.

Counters act like multisets, in that when you use 2 in an intersection like above, their counts are set to the mimimum values found in either counter, ignoring anything whose count drops to 0. If you were to compute their union, the *maximum* counts would be used instead.