# Compare 2 lists and print the element of the 2nd list if it is present in first list, but not by using 2 for loops

Tags: python, list

I have to compare 2 lists, if element of list `a` is present in list `b`, then the element of list `b` is to print.

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 1, 3]
b = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3]

ans = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
```

I may get the answer by using 2 for loops like:

```
for a_ in a:
    for b_ in b:
        if a_ == b_: 
            print b_

op: 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 3
```

But I don't want to use 2 `for` loops. How can I do that with a single loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list intersection with non unique items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253361/python-list-intersection-with-non-unique-items)

Comment: @SirParselot: *each* '1' in `a` (both of them) results in all three '1's in `b` being printed.

Comment: Why don't you want to use two for loops?  You could replace the inner loop with a list comprehension.  You could pre-process b to create a dictionary of element values to lists of the appropriate length and then concatenate copies of those.  It all depends on the background.

Comment: Are you specifically prevented from using two _nested_ `for` loops, or is `for` not allowed to appear more than once anywhere?  Arbitrary restrictions like that sound like a homework assignment, which usually have more than just one...  Any other restrictions we should know about, like standard library modules you're not allowed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter` to count for you:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(b)
ans = []
for x in a:
    ans += [x]*c.get(x,0)
```

Comment: @SirParselot Thanks for the answer, but I did not get proper answer. Got output like: `2 2 1 1 1 2 3`.

Comment: looks like you have a and b switched. when I ran my code, it gave your expected answer

Comment: Thank you very much @Fabricator. This solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I am asking just for curiosity. Is there any other method without using any built in function(like _collections_)?

Comment: Up for `+=` way to append to a list. BTW, I thought of giving my own answer, which it seems is what your have already given.

Comment: @Agsthya, like others have already answer, you can use b.count(x) instead. I think the efficiency will depend on the size of b.

Answer (score 1):

This is one potential way (a bit messy), just posting it since it turns out Fabricator didn't end up with the correct result.

```
[item for sublist in ([i] * b.count(i) for i in a) for item in sublist]
```

Basically, the `([i] * b.count(i) for i in a)` part builds the list, but it ends up as a list of lists, so then I did the `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]` thing to flatten the list.

It's probably a bit similar to the answer by zondo but this keeps it as a list of numbers instead of a string.

Comment: I think you missed the point question is get result in single loop.

Comment: Yeah I noticed haha, I wasn't going to answer until I saw the main one didn't work correctly. This way does use 2 loops, but it only uses 1 of them to build the list, and the other is just flattening the list, as opposed to the `[i  for i in a for j in b if i==j]` way

Answer (score 0):

```
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in a for _ in range(b.count(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This, should be work:

```
for a_ in a:
    if b.count(a_) :
         ans+=((str(a_)+' ')*b.count(a_)).strip().split(' ')
```

*list.count(x)* count the number of occourrences of x in list.

you can print n times a string simply: *'mystring'*times*

Hope I helped you!

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is also working. But printing results two times.